# I am unable to delete a list column in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The following error shows up in the browser console when I try to delete a column I previously added.

TypeError: form.__VIEWSTATE is undefined

form.__VIEWSTATE.value = "";

Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you pls post your code which you used?

Comment: (Issue RESOLVED!)  I reverted to an old version of the v4.master page by resetting to site definition and that solved the issue.